# Association between proportions as predictors and normally distributed response

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, descriptive-statistics, association-measure

Assume I have the following data points:

```
x1      x2      x3      x4       y
0.0001  0.0260  0.0691  0.9048   0.1
0.0001  0.0501  0.1001  0.8497  -0.3
0.0001  0.0001  0.0001  0.9997   0.2
0.1001  0.0001  0.8997  0.0001   0.3
0.9496  0.0001  0.0501  0.0001  -1.3
0.5998  0.3000  0.1001  0.0002  -3.2
.       .       .       .        .
```

where
`x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = 1`
are proportions and `y` is normally distributed.

My goal is to test if the structure of my data points in terms of proportions of Xs can explain the variation in Y. How would I properly test that? Linear regression perhaps (R squared?)

Comment: One of decisions is to remove one of four variables as redundant, then maybe log transform the three remaining. Or logistic transform.

Comment: @ttnphns: why transform? I'd just start with a straight model on the four predictors (without an intercept).

Comment: Please state your objective and hypotheses ?

Comment: what assumptions are there that could be violated following your procedure ?

Comment: I edited the question hopefully to be better understood